# how to use lookup along with $push in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I was playing with Mongodb and wanted a query that use lookup and $push or $addToSet

See this  https://mongoplayground.net/p/4hSPKW_bCdM

How can i make this query correct. do we need loop over here ?

Should return

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "_id": "5fcdcc14da26c80a6de06754",
      "first_name": "James",
      "last_name": "Hales",
      "username": "jim",
      "timestamp": 1607322644202,
      "userData": [
        {
          "_id": "6011021851781d3d9841e09d",
          "user_id": "5fcdcc14da26c80a6de06754",
          "photo": [
            {
              "_id": "6011021851781d3d9841e09e",
              "url": "http://localhost:3000/files/ou93r0cfjde0cat.jpg",
              "width": 250,
              "height": 500,
              "preview": "skjdfbsdjvns;svnsdvisdvnvsdjvnsdivsdkvsdivsdjvnsdjvsdvsdvgjsvnsvhi"
            }
          ],
          "status": "Active",
          "timestamp": 1611727384083,
          "expire_at": "2021-01-27T06:03:04.083Z"
        },
        {
          "_id": "6011021851781d3d9841e09d",
          "user_id": "5fcdcc14da26c80a6de06754",
          "photo": [
            {
              "_id": "6011021851781d3d9841e09e",
              "url": "http://localhost:3000/files/ou93r0cfjee0bat.jpg",
              "width": 250,
              "height": 500,
              "preview": "skjdfbsdjvns;svnsdvisdvnvsdjvnsdivsdkvsdivsdjvnsdjvsdvsdvgjsvnsvhi"
            }
          ],
          "status": "Active",
          "timestamp": 1611727384083,
          "expire_at": "2021-01-27T06:03:04.083Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F2_FWZY_WBg) what you want? Also, please be clearer to explain the behaviour. Paste a long document and say "I want this output" is not a good description of the problem.

Comment: Sorry should return should be expected output I did try https://mongoplayground.net/p/CIRu5cSI6s4

but there should also added users data whose site is this

Comment: Your expected result in not valid JSON, please correct and explain.

Comment: @turivishal updated the format please check

Comment: Okay, We have two users that belongs to site now I want only those user who are attached with site. How can I do that ? https://mongoplayground.net/p/CIRu5cSI6s4

Comment: No I mean each user should have matching site if Jim has two site data then it should display Jim data along with site data if Sames data exist into site then on Sames's object site data should display.

Comment: I think you need to update your question and provide proper information, see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: My bad trouble you a lot sorry for that updated my expect result please take a look

Comment: Sames should not exist if userData has not data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- *(optional)* `$match` user id in array or not
- `$lookup` with site, pass `_id` as localfield and `user_id` as foreignfield
- *(optional)* `$match` if you want to remove empty `userData` user's document

```
db.users.aggregate([
  // optional match stage
  {
    $match: {
      _id: { $in: [ObjectId("5fcdcc14da26c80a6de06754"), ObjectId("5fcdd0075dc42a0d5c7ec813")] }
    }
  }
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "site",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "userData"
    }
  },
  // optional match stage
  { $match: { userData: { $ne: [] } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vhYlw6ZiR42)